# Unable to upgrade from grails 2.3.4 to 2.4.3 - Cannot find GrailsResourceLoaderFactoryBean

Tags: grails, upgrade, grails-2.0

**PROBLEM**

I am trying to upgrade a grails app from 2.3.4 to 2.4.3 by following the instructions at this link 
http://grails.org/doc/2.4.3/guide/upgradingFrom23.html

and I do not seem to be able to accomplish it. I am getting at compile time a cannot find GrailsResourceLoaderFactoryBean initialization error. As I understand that is no longer present in grails 2.4 but it still wants it somehow. I made sure that my applicationContext.xml is exactly the same as the one generated from brand new project and the error still happens.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

1/ grails set-grails-version 2.4.3 this updated the application properties

2/ Then added the following to my BuildConfig

```
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.7'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"
    compile ":mail:1.0.7"           
    compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC3'
    compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0-RC2"
    compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"
    compile ":cache-headers:1.1.7"

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    runtime ':hibernate4:4.3.5.2' // or ':hibernate:3.6.10.14'
    runtime ':database-migration:1.4.0'
    runtime ':jquery:1.11.0.2'
    runtime ':resources:1.2.13'
    runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
```

3/ I have also removed this line from my applicationContext.xml

```
 <property name="grailsResourceLoader" ref="grailsResourceLoader" />
```

4/ I have also deleted the project under userprofile.grails\2.4.3\projects then performed a grails refresh-dependencies and still no luck!

Take a look at the stacktrace:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to the problem. Apparently, I forgot to remove the following declaration from the applicationContext.xml. I should have known better, however, this is missing in the official upgrade documentation.

```
<bean id="grailsResourceLoader" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsResourceLoaderFactoryBean" />
```

Comment: "this is missing in the official upgrade documentation." - It is mentioned in the official upgrade documentation.  The notes at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/upgradingFrom23.html include the following: "The web-app/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml file contains a bean definition for a grailsResourceLoader bean which is an instance of org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsResourceLoaderFactoryBean. That bean definition needs to be removed from the file."

Comment: See https://github.com/grails/grails-doc/commit/9bfd17397b8572ea4ca021ebde67fe7c185ee238#diff-42e722eb2e80076bbbfab0562da2dc62R20

Comment: Yep, you are right but since you are showing a screenshot of the before and after "grailsApplication" bean I think it would have been better to also explicity add the line of xml to be removed along with the text as when you read maybe kind of quickly it's easy to get overlooked. Again, no worries I should have known better from doing Spring development in the past but sometimes with everything else going on at work is easy to overlook.

Comment: Jeff is right. This is a non-issue. If you read the upgrade doumentation you would have been fine.